# Objective C: File doesn't exists in iOS but on Mac

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a Problem with a path. I want to get a file from the documents directory. I do it so:

```
NSString *imagePath =[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"category_%d/%@",self.categoryIndex,[self.header stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""]]];
```

This works on Mac, respectively when I simulate iOS on Mac, but don't work on a real iOS device. When I make an query if the path exists, I get false on the iOS device.

The path exists 100% because I see it when I open the organizer and select the device.
This is what I get as path:

```
imagePath   NSPathStore2 *  @"/var/mobile/Applications/50FEFB7C-B91F-4AEF-8406-618077D96014/Documents/category_0/theview"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hypothesis: It's because iOS paths are case-sensitive, whereas OSX paths are not.

Second hypothesis: It's because the iOS simulator's file system has different base pathnames than an iOS device.

Compare the exact path of the file that's available on an iOS device vs. the path your code is requesting.